# Defined Technical Specs for 'Broadcast Quality'

Tags: video, audio, broadcast, technical, specifications

Does anyone know if there are clear technical specs a digital file can be assessed against to confirm a valid 'broadcast quality' file?

EG: Video = certain bitrate  Audio = certain bitrate.

Obviously 'non-broadcast quality' files can be faked by resaving to meet such specs, but as a starting point are there guidelines?

Comment: Regarding HD video, it used to be either MPEG HD422 (MPEG-2 Interframe @ 50 Mbit/s, 4:2:2) or DVCPRO HD (40-100 Mbit/s, 4:2:2). Then a whole bunch of new formats came along based on AVC/H.264 and lately H.265. I think the consistent requirement over the years has been **4:2:2 color subsampling**. When HD was THE thing 10-15 years ago and TV bitrates were healthy 15+ Mbit/s, this all made sense. Nowadays my local TV station broadcasts "HD" at 5 Mbit/s, so the quality is worse than a cheap smartphone. "Broadcast quality" means nothing to me anymore. If anything, YouTube videos can look better.

Comment: Despite what Rusty Core says, TV stations will have specifications about what they regard as "broadcast quality" and will reject material that does not meet their QC checks. Best bet is to ask whatever station you are submitting it to.

Answer (score 2):

This depends entirely on who you are delivering to. Different broadcasters have different requirements.  Most have a delivery spec sheet that you can request, or that they publish online. e.g. [here's the BBC one](https://www.bbc.co.uk/commissioning/tv/production/articles/technical-requirements).

Comment: BBC link was quite handy, thanks

Comment: And here are the [Netflix](https://partnerhelp.netflixstudios.com/hc/en-us/articles/214806618-Netflix-Originals-Delivery-Specifications-v3-2-1) and [PBS](http://bento.cdn.pbs.org/hostedbento-prod/filer_public/PBS_About/Producing/Red%20Book/TOS%20Pt%201%20Submission%202016.pdf) specs.

Answer (score 0):

you need to understand the meaning of each & effect of different Bit-rates
on your video.

DEPENDING ON PAL & NTSC 
FRAME SIZE, FRAME RATE & FIELD PROGRESSION CHANGES
FOR THAT TOPIC

[CLICK ON THIS TEXT OTHERWISE READ THE FOLLOWINGS:](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/video/part06.html)

> **SD**
>   `4 MB/s = TARGERT BITRATE & 5 MB/s AS MAX BITRARTE`

& there won't be much difference.
but for

> **HD**
>   `8 MB/s = TARGERT BITRATE & 12 MB/s AS MAX BITRARTE`

AS FOR

> **AUDIO FREQ.**  `48k`

Comment: Does 'broadcast quality' (as a term) still apply for Online Delivery?

Comment: yes, it does, in fact, go to the link below for Youtube Standard broadcast Settings         https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en